# Show multiple tax_query from 2 or more post_type in a single code

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, post-type, tax-query

i've been trying with no success to show 2 custom taxonomies from 2 post_type, here's my code:

```
<?php
                /**
                 * Display a list of the most recent news in 'Avisos'
                 *
                 */
                $avisos_query = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type' => array('noticia','comunicado'),
                    'posts_per_page' => 5,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'clasificacion',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => 'avisos'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'anos',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => '2011'
                        )
                    )
                ) );
                // Display the custom loop
                if ( $avisos_query->have_posts() ): 
            ?>
```

I've been searching around here and WP but nothing.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you confirmed that there are posts that have BOTH terms assigned to them?

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself, the problem was the 'AND', must be 'OR', thank you anyway.